# Schema for mixing HTML and XML (not "including XHTML in XML")

Tags: xml, xsd, xhtml

It's easy to embed some XHTML in an XML document, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<mannual:product xmlns:mannual="http://product/mannual" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  ...
  <mannual:instruction>
    <p>Before proceeding, 
       <strong>make sure you put on your safety goggles</strong>.
       Start by unlocking the airlock...
    </p>
  </mannual:instruction>
  ....
</mannual:product>
```

This can be done with XML schema `<import>` importing XHTML's `xsd` files and defining element `<mannual:instruction>` to have the type `xhtml.div.type`

But what if we wish to mix XML and HTML? Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<mannual:product xmlns:mannual="http://product/mannual" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  ...
  <mannual:instruction>
    <p><mannual:information>Before proceeding, 
         <strong>make sure you put on your safety goggles</strong>.
       </mannual:information>
       <mannual:action>
         Start by unlocking the airlock...
       </mannual:action>
    </p>
  </mannual:instruction>
  ....
</mannual:product>
```

As you can see, in the XHTML segment some XML elements (`<information>` and `<action>`) are used. Defining `instruction` to be of `xhtml.div.type` would not pass validation in such case. How can we define schema to allow such flexibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammars require clear definition; hand-waving descriptions about mixing won't cut it.

Your HTML and XML "mix" has no such clear definition.  To see this you need look no further than your example's `p` element.  HTML does not define a `p` element to have `manual:information` child elements.

So, you can

- Roll up your sleeves and write a proper grammar for your new grammar, or
- Punt, and use `xsd:any` to allow any well-formed markup where you wish to mix HTML and XML, foregoing the ability to validate against an actual grammar there.

Comment: Such information that there is no middle ground between `xsd:any` and define rules for every XHTML elements where such mixing is allowed would satisfy my original curiosity.

Comment: In XSD 1.1 additional qualifications can be added to `xsd:any` content via `xsd:assert`.